# How to match a special character?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression query

```
^(show/tiger\+season\+2/video)$
```

which should match

> show/tiger+season+2/video

This is being tested in IIS and is not working. Any suggestions

Comment: you need `[+]` or `\+`

Comment: What is not working? if you have e.g. `/` also as regex delimiter, then you need to escape your slashes too.

Comment: i have / in my other regex queries and they seem to work fine. I have a doubt that the regex is not working because of the + symbol. Have found out that + is taken by the browser for space, so i have also tried /s but that too doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding backslash before the special character.

IE:

```
 ^(show/tiger\+season\+2/video)$
```